# Call to static overloaded (class) function/method is ambiguous

Tags: c++, oop, static-functions

In my C++ class, I have two static methods, called getInstance.

The method declarations are as follows:

```
public: // +++ STATIC +++
    static CanCommunicator* getInstance(shared_ptr<ThreadState> state);
    static CanCommunicator* getInstance();
```

In a global function (required, because of legacy code), I'm calling a getter from the object:

```
auto tState = CanCommunicator::getInstance()->getThreadState();
```

The compiler (GCC 4.4.5) is giving me the following error:

```
CanCommunicator::getInstance is ambiguous
Candidates are:
CanCommunicator * getInstance()
CanCommunicator * getInstance(std::shared_ptr<IsoTpThreadState>)
```

What is causing this error and how can I fix it?
The overloaded method is required for instance creation, the method without parameters is used for pure instance retrieval.

**EDIT: As per request more code for the example.**

```
#include <memory>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <linux/can.h>
#include <linux/can/raw.h>

using std::shared_ptr;

//================
// Class in question
//================

struct ThreadState {
    int32_t socketFd;
    uint32_t sendId;
};

class CanCommunicator {
    #define null NULL

    public: // +++ STATIC +++
        static CanCommunicator* getInstance(shared_ptr<ThreadState> state);
        static CanCommunicator* getInstance();
    public:
        shared_ptr<ThreadState> getThreadState() { return this->threadState; }
    protected:
        CanCommunicator(shared_ptr<ThreadState> state);
    private: // +++ STATIC +++
        static CanCommunicator* instance;
    private:
        shared_ptr<ThreadState> threadState;
};


/*
 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 +++       STATIC VARIABLES        +++
 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 */

CanCommunicator* CanCommunicator::instance = null;


/*
 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 +++        STATIC METHODS         +++
 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 */

CanCommunicator* CanCommunicator::getInstance(shared_ptr<ThreadState> state) {
    if (state == null && instance == null)
        throw "Cannot instantiate from nullptr!";

    return instance == null ? (instance = new CanCommunicator(state)) : instance;
}

CanCommunicator* CanCommunicator::getInstance() { return instance == null ? throw "No instance found!" : instance; }

CanCommunicator::CanCommunicator(shared_ptr<ThreadState> state) {
    this->threadState = state;        
}

//================
// Calling code
//================

int canSendData(int32_t skt, uint32_t sendCanId, const uint8_t* data, uint8_t dataLength, uint8_t extended) {
    struct can_frame myCanFrame;
    return (int)write(skt, &myCanFrame, sizeof(myCanFrame));
}

int isotp_user_send_can(const uint32_t arbitrationId, const uint8_t* data, const uint8_t size) {
    auto tState = CanCommunicator::getInstance()->getThreadState(); //<-------- Error originates here
    return canSendData(tState->socketFd, (int)tState->sendId, data, size, false) > 0 ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Comment: The code as posted should not generate this error.  Can we get a [mre] please?

Comment: The code I posted is (apart from two small changes) the code I used and was intended to be used as the example. Give me two minutes, I'll cobble something together.

Comment: My guess: You're not calling the function directly, but trying to create a function pointer, and that is where the error is happening (not casting the function pointer to the appropriate signature to resolve the ambiguity)

Comment: @AndyG How would I not be calling the function directly? It's a static function being called with Object::staticFunction() - AFAIK that's the way to call any function

Comment: @SimonC: I was guessing in lieu of actual code

Comment: Ah, my bad. Well, I added the code I'm using to the OP. Looks to me as if it should work. That's the only thing GCC is complaining about

Comment: Provided code (with missing functions) works [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/807e1dabbb78a400).

Comment: [I still cannot reproduce the error](https://godbolt.org/z/0ybc1u).  Can we please get a copy pasteable [mre]?

Comment: @NathanOliver That is literally the code copy-pasted out of my IDE. The fact that it is not reproducible suggests that I may have stumbled on a bug?

Comment: @SimonC Well, the fact I had to add a bunch of dummy code means it isn't a literal copy and paste.  We should be able to copy the single code block, paste it into our compilers, and run it.  That we can't do that means it could be a bug, or you could have a copy paste error.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but that ternary operator for the return from `getInstance(shared_ptr<ThreadState>)` is very hard to read. Break it up: `if (instance == null) instance = new CanCommunicator(state); return instance;`.

Comment: Sadly I can't C&P the entire class. 
The canSendData function is irrelevant to the error, hence why I didn't include it. I added the constructor to the ccode, along with the method for getting the ThreadState.

Comment: @PeteBecker I personally find it easier to read than having three extra lines of (IMO redundant) code - at least in this case. Granted, there are cases where the ternary operator isn't welcome: for me this isn't one of those cases

Comment: After few fixes i got it to compile. Looks like a compiler bug, clang deals with it just fine. `ggc 4.45` is **dated**, can you upgrade your compiler? Current version is 9.1...

Comment: @SimonC -- there's nothing redundant in the code I suggested. The problem with the use of the ternary operator here is that it's used for its side effects: one branch has a side effect and the other doesn't, but both evaluate to the same thing.

Comment: @RadosławCybulski Sadly no. At least not yet. I'm dealing with a ten year-old Linux version on (essentially) 20 Y/O hardware. The next revision used 6.3 which hopefully will fix a lot of the issues we're having

Comment: Maybe rename offending `getInstance(std::shared_ptr<IsoTpThreadState>)` to - for example - `getInstanceByState(std::shared_ptr<IsoTpThreadState>)`?

Comment: I'll give it a try.

Comment: Can't reproduce with gcc-4.4.7. Take a look at https://godbolt.org/z/Ny04_z

Comment: @MichaelVeksler I'm using 4.4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Radoslaw's suggestion, I simply renamed the offending function to getInstanceByState().

This seems to be a bug in the version of GCC (4.4.5) I'm using, so there is no true fix but to wait until I can use a (much) newer compiler version.

Thank you to all who helped and gave suggestions.

Comment: seems a very strange bug. If you rename it back to original do you get the error?

Comment: Yes, if I rename the method back the same behaviour occurs.